# how to call grand child tables in the Queryable include statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

Suppose I have the following three tables

- A
- B
- C

There is 1 to many relationship between the tables as follows:

- A->B
- B->C

I am using Entity framework to query the table and the programming is in C#.
Suppose, I need all the columns in A, I do the following:

`var query = _context.A;
query.where( <where clause> )`

If I need to include the columns of B to prevent lazy loading,

```
query.Include ( s => s.B );
```

The question is, how do I include the columns of C to prevent lazy loading?
I am looking for something like:

`query.Include ( s => s.B.C )` ( This does not work because of the 1 to many relationship between the tables )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your third level as part of your query as I show below:

```
query.Include (s => s.B.Select(b=>b.C));
```

If you go to **Remarks** section in this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx), you will find several examples how to include different levels using `Include` extension method.